# how can i use for/loop in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

to merge single image in top of video i use

```
  String imagePath =  '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20221010_002819.jpg';
  String videoPath =  '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20221010_002833.mp4';
  String outPutPath = '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/output.mp4';

  String comand = '-y -i $videoPath -i $imagePath -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=600:600[ovrl];[0:v][ovrl]overlay=200:200" $outPutPath';
```

**question** what if i have list of images with unknown length ?

```
List imagesList = ['url1','url2','url3',etc....]
```

does ffmpeg support for/loop ?
if yes how could i use `myimagesList` into my previous command ?

Comment: search for how to use `image2` demuxer.

Comment: If files names don't corporate with `image2`, you can also look into `concat` demuxer

Comment: i have seen something like this .. for %%a in ('*output') do {.....} do you think this is my case?